# MySQL replace string with dynamic value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to replace a String with dynamic value inside it?
For example, I have this query:

```
UPDATE wp_widget_instances 
SET coordinates = REPLACE(coordinates,'"tablet":{"sizex":1,"sizey":7,','"tablet":{"sizex":1,"sizey":8,')
WHERE coordinates like '%"tablet":{"sizex":1,"sizey":7,%' ;
```

I would like to the same thing but not only for `"sizex":1` but for all possible value  of `sizex ("sizex":2 , "sizex":3, ...)`

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,